# How can I map a complex number to a qubit in Q#?

Tags: complex-numbers, q#, qubit

In theory, the state of a qubit is defined by 2 complex numbers, following this formula:

[image: Image for formula of qubit superposition state]

The rule is that the amount of complex numbers needed to define the state of a set of qubits is equal to 2ⁿ, where n is the number of used qubits.

if i have an array of complex numbers, how can I map or assign each number to a qubit?

For instance:
I have this complex number: 0.0020908999722450972 + i*0.001669629942625761.
What would the state of a qubit be in this case?
Would I be needing more qubits to represent this number?

Answer (score 2):

I think that depends on what are you going to do with these numbers after you have mapped them to qubits.

If you need to use 2ⁿ numbers to prepare a quantum state on n qubits that is a weighted superposition of the basis states, you can use [PrepareArbitraryState](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/qsharp/api/qsharp/microsoft.quantum.preparation.preparearbitrarystate) operation which does exactly that. Internally it implements the paper [Synthesis of Quantum Logic Circuits](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0406176) by Shende, Bullock, Markov.

If you need to represent these numbers in a way that would allow you to read them out by measuring the qubits, you might have to do something like convert them in binary and store each bit in a separate qubit.

Comment: Unfortunatelly my input does not have a fixed size. I have a vague sensation that I might need something of both your suggestions.
What I'm trying to do is implement in Q# the NonUniform Discrete Fourier Transform.
I am doing this because I need to convert data generated by a Siemens MRI scanner into an image (long story short).
My input is an array of complex numbers which undergoes a series of transformations until I get to apply the NDFT. I might need n qubits for each number, but in terms of encoding or setting the values, doing something and then measuring ... that's the tricky part.